# Filterable not working as expected in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

So I am tried to implement a filterable search in my application, it is suppose to start filtering at the moment of typing. But that never happens. And instead of showing the wanted items, it just keeps the same items and remove from down up according to the number of items found. For example, if the adapter has 4 items,

Banana
Apple
Orange
Lemon

Search string "e"
it will show:
Banana
Apple
Orange

because there is 3 items contain "e", and it will show the first 3.
The adapter below:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private static final String LOG_TAG = MenuListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private int mResourceId;
private ArrayList<Items> items;
private ArrayList<Items> itemsCopy;
private Context context;
private ClickListener clickListener;
private ItemsDAO itemsDAO;
private TextView category_description;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> items, LayoutInflater inflater, int resourceId, TextView category_description) {
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    itemsCopy = new ArrayList<>();
    this.items.addAll(items);
    itemsCopy.addAll(items);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size());
    this.context = context;
    mLayoutInflater = inflater;
    mResourceId = resourceId;
    this.category_description = category_description;
}

/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
 */
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    TextView price;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        title = v.findViewById(R.id.menu_title);
        image = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        price = v.findViewById(R.id.menu_price);
        itemsDAO = new ItemsDAO(v.getContext());

        //Swipe languages
        if(Languages.getLocale(context).equals("en")) {
            title.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(context, AppUtils.FONT_REGULAR));
            price.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(context, AppUtils.FONT_MEDIUM));
            category_description.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(context, AppUtils.FONT_MEDIUM));
        }
        else {
            title.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(context, AppUtils.AR_FONT_LIGHT));
            price.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(context, AppUtils.FONT_MEDIUM));
            category_description.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(context, AppUtils.AR_FONT_MEDIUM));
        }

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition(), items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), false);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            }
        });

        v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition(), items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), true);

                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}

// Create new view (invoked by the layout manager)
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mResourceId, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    //    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

    final Items menuItems = items.get(position);

    category_description.setText(itemsDAO.getCategoryDescription(menuItems.getCategory_code()+ 9000));
    // Get element from MenuItems object at this position and replace the contents of the view
    // with that element
    //IMAGE STATIC HERE
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Base64.decode(menuItems.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT), 0, Base64.decode(menuItems.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT).length);
    viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    viewHolder.image.setTag(menuItems.getId());
    //Swipe languages
    if(Languages.getLocale(context).equals("en")) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(menuItems.getName());
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.title.setText(menuItems.getName2());
    }

    viewHolder.price.setText(Localization.getLocalize(context) + " " + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(menuItems.getPrice())));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener = clickListener;

}


// An interface to Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View from any where.
public interface ClickListener{
    void itemClicked(View view, int position, int id, boolean isLongClick);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            items.clear();
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                items.addAll(itemsCopy);
            } else {
                charString = charString.toLowerCase();
                int counter = 0;
                for(Items item: itemsCopy){
                    if(item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)){
                        items.add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        notifyItemRemoved(counter);
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = items;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            items = (ArrayList<Items>) filterResults.values;

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}}
```

The searchView code in the fragment

```
case R.id.action_search: {
            android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) item.getActionView();
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(
                    new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                            menuListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                            menuListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
            );

            return true;
        }
```

Here is what is happening, nothing changes while typing:

[image: while type]

After submitting the search, this what happens, there are 3 items contains "ca" so it shows only the first 3 items:

[image]

And when I click on the first item, it passes the correct id and will navigate to a correct filtered item which contains "ca".

[image]

## This is for pskink

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<Items, MenuListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String LOG_TAG = MenuListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private ClickListener clickListener;
private ItemsDAO itemsDAO;
private TextView category_description;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Items> objects, TextView category_description) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.category_description = category_description;

}

/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
 */
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    TextView price;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        title = v.findViewById(R.id.menu_title);
        image = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        price = v.findViewById(R.id.menu_price);
        itemsDAO = new ItemsDAO(v.getContext());

        //Swipe languages
        if(Languages.getLocale(getContext()).equals("en")) {
            title.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(getContext(), AppUtils.FONT_REGULAR));
            price.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(getContext(), AppUtils.FONT_MEDIUM));
            category_description.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(getContext(), AppUtils.FONT_MEDIUM));
        }
        else {
            title.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(getContext(), AppUtils.AR_FONT_LIGHT));
            price.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(getContext(), AppUtils.AR_FONT_MEDIUM));
            category_description.setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeface(getContext(), AppUtils.AR_FONT_MEDIUM));
        }

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition(), getAdapterPosition(), false);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            }
        });

        v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition(), getAdapterPosition(), true);

                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}


@Override
protected ViewHolder onCreateHolder(View view) {
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
protected void onBindHolder(Items item, ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    category_description.setText(itemsDAO.getCategoryDescription(item.getCategory_code()+ 9000));
    // Get element from MenuItems object at this position and replace the contents of the view
    // with that element
    //IMAGE STATIC HERE
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Base64.decode(item.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT), 0, Base64.decode(item.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT).length);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    holder.image.setTag(item.getId());
    //Swipe languages
    if(Languages.getLocale(getContext()).equals("en")) {
        holder.title.setText(item.getName());
    }
    else {
        holder.title.setText(item.getName2());
    }

    holder.price.setText(Localization.getLocalize(getContext()) + " " + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(item.getPrice())));

}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener = clickListener;

}


// An interface to Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View from any where.
public interface ClickListener{
    void itemClicked(View view, int position, int id, boolean isLongClick);
}

@Override
protected boolean matches(Items value, CharSequence constraint, CharSequence lowerCaseConstraint) {
    return super.matches(value, constraint, lowerCaseConstraint);
}}
```

And still when I start typing nothing changes:

[image: while type]

After submitting the search, this what happens, there are 3 items contains "ca" so it shows only the first 3 items:

[image]

And when I click on the first item, it passes the correct id and will navigate to a correct filtered item which contains "ca".

[image]

Comment: extend [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic `Filterable` adapter and override `matches()` method

Comment: something like `class A extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<Items, A.VH> { ...`

Comment: and of course you dont need stuff like that: `private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private int mResourceId;
private ArrayList<Items> items;
private ArrayList<Items> itemsCopy;
private Context context;` - simply remove it

Comment: I extended your class to my adapter class, and it still shows the same items but decreases the size of the list according to the found items size.

Comment: whats your modified code then? and what you mean by `" and it still shows the same items"`?

Comment: I just edited my post, check it

Comment: you did not implement `matches` method: see parameters passed to that method and return either true or false if given `Items value` matches `constraint` or not (you can also use `lowerCaseConstraint`)

Comment: Nope, maybe I am doing it wrong, still trying..

Comment: doesn't filtering work? what you return from `matches` method? add `Log.d` inside `matches` method and log `value.getName()`, `constraint` and the returned boolean, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: `return value.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseConstraint);` . But the method never called while searching using this, `menuListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);`.

Comment: how come? are you sure you call `menuListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);`? is your `query` not null and not empty?
 setup a breakpoint [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85#file-matchablervarrayadapte-pure-recyclerview-style-no-implicit-textview-mapping-L332) and do some steps, (also you can add a breakpoint [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85#file-matchablervarrayadapte-pure-recyclerview-style-no-implicit-textview-mapping-L307))

Comment: Was a bug with my previous apk, but it is calling it now and from the log.d it seems that the filtering is working, but still the recyclerview won't update, just like the previous screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/wGeRQWL

Comment: it is as simple as [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/qtqBdkgC) - you can click on each item and watch the logcat to be sure items are mapped correctly (the filtering is based on `displayName`)

Comment: Nope it doesn't, still trying to find alternative methods.

Comment: did you try my [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/qtqBdkgC)? without no modifications? just copy & paste? what does not work? what do you see if you type `peso` for example? what do you see on the logcat when you click on any item (before and after filtering)?

Comment: Okay, your code is working, which make me re type my code, and I found that the AlphaInAnimationAdapter I am implementing is causing the problem. Thanks for your help! It is working now flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that implementing AlphaInAnimationAdapter is causing the issue, I just had to remove

```
alphaAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(menuListAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(alphaAdapter));
```

from my code and it is now working flawlessly with Pskink adapter class. Thanks Pskink for your help!